# how to place icon inside input tag in asp.net mvc5?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am new to asp.net mvc5. I was trying to put search icon inside search bar but it appears outside the bar. can any one tell the solution? here is snapshot and code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwYA2.png)

and code is here..

```
    <div class="banner-g">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="user-info">
                <div class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                    <form action="/home/browse" id="searchForm" method="get">

                        <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
                            <a href="#" id="submitSearch" style="text-decoration: none; right: 14px; color: rgb(204, 204, 204); top: 6px; "> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a>
                            <input class="form-control input-sm" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Search must be a string with a maximum length of 150." data-val-length-max="150" data-val-regex="Please only use letters, numbers, spaces, periods, commas, question/ exclamation marks, dollar sign, underscores, hyphens, apostrophes, parentheses, forward and back slashes, colon and semi colons" data-val-regex-pattern="^[0-9a-zA-Z/&#39;() .,!?$:-;_-]+$" id="Search" name="Search" placeholder="Search Markets" type="text" value="" />
                            &nbsp;

                            <input type="hidden" name="isSearch" value="true">
                        </div>

                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and in bootstrap file

```
.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

I will be thankful for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into using the Bootstrap input group component.  You can find it documented [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups).

Like this:

```
<div class="input-group">  
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bg80kagh/1/).

Comment: its still not inside the box :(

Comment: Oops you are right.... I forgot the `input-group-addon` class on the `<span />`. I will update my answer with a demo

Comment: It works in the demo I posted. Maybe you have some styles that adversely affecting it. Do you have any styles you wrote being applied to the elements in question? Like maybe styles for `inner-addon` or `left-addon`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track but your issue is a two part issue. You can use `.input-group-addon` to place the search icon next to the search input. Then you can use css to style it to look like it is part of the search bar. Style it however your heart desires.

Here is a working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mmcshinsky/hhjyqgcc/4/).